# SQL update column1 with column2 in another table that have same word

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM providerpaymentdetails, remarkcode;
```

providerpaymentdetails has columns:
**id, amount, text, remark_code_id**

remarkcode has columns:
**id, code**

if providerpaymentdetails.text has `text` that contains "B2", "B3", I want to update the `remark_code_id` with the correlating id from `remarkcode.code` which contains "B2", "B3", etc.

This is the code I have right now, but this is not working. Any ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM providerpaymentdetails, remarkcode;
UPDATE providerpaymentdetails
set REMARK_CODE_ID = remark_code.id 
WHERE providerpaymentdetails.TEXT LIKE '%B2'
```

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub select, for instance - somewhat like this:

```
UPDATE providerpaymentdetails
   set REMARK_CODE_ID = (SELECT id
                           FROM remarkcode
                          WHERE code LIKE '%B2')
 WHERE providerpaymentdetails.TEXT LIKE '%B2';
```

If the sub select is not unique, you might select the first (using LIMIT) or the maximum id:

```
UPDATE providerpaymentdetails
   set REMARK_CODE_ID = (SELECT MAX(id)
                           FROM remarkcode
                          WHERE code LIKE '%B2')
 WHERE providerpaymentdetails.TEXT LIKE '%B2';
```

***Update:***

If `code` and `text` are equal, this works:

```
UPDATE providerpaymentdetails ppd
   set REMARK_CODE_ID = (SELECT MAX(id)
                           FROM remarkcode
                          WHERE code = ppd.text)
 WHERE ppd.TEXT LIKE '%B2' 
    OR ppd.TEXT LIKE '%B3'
    OR ppd.TEXT LIKE '%B4';
```

Alternatively you could check the MySQL documentation about [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

Comment: is there an easy way I can do this for adding more codes like 'B2', 'B3' , 'B4' etc?

Comment: Edit: instead of copy pasting these 5 lines of code for every B2, B3, B4. Is there an easier way to incorporate that?

Comment: @Mdjon26 I told you ...  post some sample data and expected output.